# How to do a JSON encoded GET request with AFNetworking-2.0?

Tags: ios, json, rest, get, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to use a pattern similar [to this post which describes doing a PUT/POST for RESTful API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259946/wanted-up-to-date-example-for-json-post-with-basic-auth-using-afnetworking-2), but for a GET.

My original code looks almost the same, except I used a `GET:` keyword. I quickly discovered that rather than sending a JSON body, it instead url encodes the parameters. This is not mentioned in the documentation of the `AFJSONSerializer` class. You have to go to the superclass documentation (`AFHTTPSerializer`) and read through its properties, where you'll find [the one about HTTPMethodsEncodingParametersInURI](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.3/Classes/AFHTTPRequestSerializer.html#//api/name/HTTPMethodsEncodingParametersInURI). By default that set is populated with HEAD, GET, and DELETE. So for those types of requests, the JSON serializer apparently reverts to its parent class for behavior?

So I put together the following code:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager* manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer.HTTPMethodsEncodingParametersInURI = [NSSet set];
[manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername: currentUser() password: currentPassword()];
[manager
    GET: @"https://172.16.214.214:44321/trees"
    parameters: [NSDictionary dictionary]
    success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask* task, id responseObject){
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);}
    failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask* task, NSError* error){
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);}];
```

The line that sets `HTTPMethodsEncodingParametersInURI = [NSSet set]` is intended to let me get JSON encoded parameters like I wanted for the GET too. Unfortunately, I see nothing at the server when I use this and get the following in my error console:

```
2013-12-10 10:11:14.149 myValve[957:60b] Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The
network connection was lost." UserInfo=0x17e5d4b0
{NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://172.16.214.214:44321/trees,
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://172.16.214.214:44321/trees, NSLocalizedDescription=The network
connection was lost., NSUnderlyingError=0x17e53240 "The network connection was lost."}
```

What am I still missing?

Comment: I wish that was actually an answer @Rob. The link helped make it clear why the framework was probably not supporting it. Thanks.

Comment: I have posted it as an answer. I just didn't want to seem like I was taking credit for other people's excellent answers. Likewise, I'm always hesitant to post an answer that can be read as "don't do it." lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rationale behind AFNetworking's behavior here is probably most concisely explained in the Stack Overflow question, [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body). One of those answers [quotes Ray Fielding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/1271826):

> ... In other words, any HTTP request message is allowed to contain a message body, and thus must parse messages with that in mind. Server semantics for GET, however, are restricted such that a body, if any, has no semantic meaning to the request. The requirements on parsing are separate from the requirements on method semantics.
>
> So, yes, you can send a body with GET, and no, it is never useful to do so.

The [HTTP/1.1 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-53) defines `GET` to "retrieve whatever information (in the form of an entity) is identified by the Request-URI" and does not contemplate information to be included in the body of the request. So the use of the body in `GET` request technically might not be prohibited, but, at best, it is non-standard. AFNetworking's choice not to support it is not entirely surprising.

So, you might not want to put JSON in the body for a `GET` requests. One would generally add the parameters to the URL. If you want to send JSON in the body of the request, then do a `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it can't connect to the server, have you tried to make a call outside iOS?

For reference I normally make a JSON request like this:

```
NSURL *url = @"https://172.16.214.214:44321/trees";
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```